# no implicit conversion between string and system windows form dialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I am getting error. I like to show message dialog if cell is empty after click a button

```
 var name = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value != null ? dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString() : MessageBox.Show("Cell is empty") ;
```

Comment: you seem to have a misunderstanding of how the [? :](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) operator works in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it like that.Because the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) says:

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the **same**, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

Use an `if` statement instead:

```
string name;
if(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value == null)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Cell is empty");
}
else
{
   name = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not ever do this, Selman22's answer should be the way to go.

But just for fun: (return value "OK", "Cancel" etc when Message Box is shown)

```
var name = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value != null ? dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString() : new Func<string>(() => MessageBox.Show("Cell is empty").ToString())();
```